# QGIS 2.12 Server returns empty WFS data

Tags: wfs, error, qgis-server, getfeature

On Windows 7, QGIS 2.12 Server returns no features on a GetFeature WFS request while WFS DescribeFeatureType request and WMS requests are OK.

Does anybody have similar problems with QGIS server 2.12 ?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?